# When should a function be standalone and when should it be in a type class? Is it just a matter of taste?

Tags: haskell

Take for example the `fromIntegral` function:

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

To check whether it is:

- in the type class `Integral`
- in the type class `Num`
- in some other type class
- standalone, not in any type class

We can use `:info fromIntegral` to find out.

It turns out **it's standalone**.

But why? Why wasn't it made to be part of either the `Integral` or `Num` typeclass (or some other typeclass)? Is there any good reason for it or is it more a matter of taste?

The answer for this example will help me answer the same question in general when designing my own custom type classes and functions.

Comment: I'm really glad that you state your goal in knowing this. A short answer: if you want to learn good API design, don't look at `fromIntegral` and `Integral`, or any other part of of Haskell's numeric type class tower.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't the reason `fromIntegral` is standalone, but there is a particular benefit to this being the case.  As a standalone function, it's much simpler to define rewrite RULES to operate on `fromIntegral` (class methods get name-mangled), and this can make a huge difference for performance.  But in general, functions should be standalone unless they're an integral part of a class's meaning.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fromIntegral` is defined as

```
fromIntegral = fromInteger . toInteger
```

The two functions are in `Num` and `Integral` classes respectively. When you include a function in a class, you're saying that it might to be defined differently for different types. `fromIntegral` does not.